# reading and writing packets to a pcap file

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I have used wireshark to capture a packet and save it in a pcap file . 
Now I want to read this packet from the file and write into another file n number of times .
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't clear enough.

- If you want only to **take a file and append it to itself** (you can choose the *merge* option of wireshark in file->merge - read more [here](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOMergeSection.html)).
  But without editing it you'll get a lot of duplicate acks and other "weird stuff" - because sequence numbers would be kept the same (if you just copy of course).
- If you want to do a **whole editing process** you should consider pcap editing tools such as: *bittwist, libcrafter, editcap (suppose to be in your wireshark installation folder) or powereditpcap* (of course you can find others :)).

Hope that gave you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

To open the pcap file, you would use :

```
pcap_t *pcap, *handle;
char errbuf [PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap = pcap_open_offline(argv[1],errbuf);
```

If pcap!=NULL, then you have successfully opened the pcap file. Now you can just loop through the file till you reach the end of the file.

```
struct pcap_pkthdr header;
const unsigned char *packet;
for (i = 0; (packet = pcap_next(pcap, &header)) != NULL; i++) {
   <do what you want to do with the packet using the packet pointer>
}
```